# Do lots of operations on multiple objects of the same type

Tags: c#, iteration

I have two graphical objects (say some kind of `Table`s) and I want to set their styles. The trivial code is as follows:

```
table1.BorderWidth = 2;
table1.BorderColor = Color.GloriousPink;

table2.BorderWidth = 2;
table2.BorderColor = Color.GloriousPink;
```

(The real code has more lines.)

A more clever way is using a method.

```
void Format Table(int tableIndex)
{
    Table table;
    if(tableIndex == 1)
        table = table1;
    if(tableIndex == 2)
        table = table2;
    table.BorderWidth = 2;
    table.BorderColor = Color.GloriousPink;
}
```

I was thinking of a way to make it more scalable (the `if`/`switch` part grows fast), and I came up with:

```
foreach(Table table in new List<Table> { table1, table2 })
{
    table.BorderWidth = 2;
    table.BorderColor = Color.GloriousPink;
}
```

This is shorter and any potential additional tables are added quite simply. Is there any downside to it?

Comment: That's about it. Duplicate code and multiple `if` statements are a common code smell.

Comment: Your second method could be a little cleverer. Instead of accepting an `int tableIndex` as parameter, you could take a `Table table` instead. `void FormatTable(Table table)`. This way you won't need an `if` and your code gets shorter and more easy to read too.

Comment: You might also consider having a list as a private field of the parent class, containing all your tables (to avoid having to recreate the list whenever you want to apply operations to all tables).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Nothing jumps out as being wrong, but I'd go with your original idea and actually put that in a method, just instead pass in the actual table.

```
public void Format(Table table)
{
    table.BorderWidth = 2;
    table.BorderColor = Color.GloriousPink;
}

foreach(Table table in tables) 
{
   Format(table);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't know your requirements, but how about some functional style:

```
Action<Table> formatTable = (table) => {
    table.BorderWidth = 2;
    table.BorderColor = Color.GloriousPink;
};

new List<Table> { table1, table2 }.ForEach(formatTable);
```

---

If you don't like all these `Action` thing:

```
void FormatTable(Table table)
{
    table.BorderWidth = 2;
    table.BorderColor = Color.GloriousPink;
}

new List<Table>{ table1, table2 }.ForEach(FormatTable);
```

Comment: This might be an overkill for such a simple operation, unless the applied function needs to be interchanged during runtime.

Comment: Idea is that he can have member of a class `ApplyTable` and pass it to `ForEach`

Comment: He does say that it's an overly simple example and likely to grow...

Comment: that's why we try to overuse code as max as possible

Answer (score 2):

Let the compiler create the array:

```
void FormatTable(params Table[] tables)
{
    foreach(var table in tables)
    {
        table.BorderWidth = 2;
        table.BorderColor = Color.GloriousPink;
    }
}
```

and call it like so:

```
FormatTables( table1, table2);
```